# Shell Script - compactar um arquivo por vez dentro da Pasta corrente

Tags: bash

É o seguinte pessoal ... vou explicar nos mínimo detalhes, de forma simples pra ilustrar a idéia.

## Exemplo

```
for N in `ls $HOME`
do
    tar zcvf `basename`.tgz $N
done
```

> Veja que quero compactar *O diretório de origem juntamente com um arquivo por vez* ficando assim:

/home/user/0.tgz

/home/user/1.tgz

/home/user/2.tgz

etc ...

**Para isso ocorrer, é preciso compactar o arquivo seguido de seu caminho de origem**

Comment: O objeto de um arquivo `tar` é ser uma coleção de arquivos, para depois aplicar a compressão gzip em cima e transformar em um `.tar.gz`, ou `tgz` por curto. O ideal para o seu caso seria rodar apenas o gzip sobre os arquivos

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Se por acaso puder me ajudar com um exemplo prático com *gz* ou *zip*, ja agradeço

Comment: Não vou dar uma resposta completa, mas tenta `for f in ./*; do gzip "$f"; done `

Comment: Referência do gzip que usei https://www.lifewire.com/example-uses-of-the-linux-gzip-command-4078675

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Tudo bem! Alias estou tentando ja se faz 1 hora. rsrs

Comment: shell script é isso mesmo. Um dia ele não dá rasteira na gente. Me marca aqui quando tiver o resultado da sugestão que eu dei

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Quase lá! Com esta tentativa - **for N in `ls $HOME/*`; do gzip -f "$N"; done**. O que falta é compactar a pasta com seu arquivo incluso fazendo assim sucessivamente para cada qual arquivo em particular. Mas sou grato pelo seu comentário. :D

Comment: Subpasta também? Isso é trabalho para o `find pasta/`... hoje eu preciso ir, espero ter ajudado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Então [Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado), como pediu [...]Me marca aqui quando tiver o resultado da sugestão que eu dei. Estou lhe avisando que consegui o que queria. Abraços.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que o maior problema aqui é o de arquivos/diretório com espaço em branco. O comando abaixo procura por qualquer arquivo/diretório a partir do diretório atual e executa o tar com os parâmetros desejados, tratando espaços em branco:

```
find . -name \* -print0 -exec tar -zcvf '{}'.tgz '{}' \;
```

Comment: Uau! Vou testar sua dica. Apesar de ter concluido hoje uma solução um tanto parecido com a sua, mas usa 3 linhas. Ja estava a preparar para postar. Mas em todo caso vou disponibilizar aqui para fins de alternativa e lógica de programação.

Comment: Perfeito! Aceite o meu upVote seguido do meu voto absoluto. vlw!

Comment: É sempre bom poder ajudar! Valeu, [ ].

Comment: Dá uma olhada no que havia feito antes, coloquei o script que escrevi na resposta para agregar valor ao poste e lógico contriubuir com a comunidade experiência.

Comment: Vi agora. Acho que há um erro no do find /* . Não seria do find $HOME ?

Comment: Mas tente executar desta maneira como mencionou [...]Acho que há um erro no do find /* . Não seria do find $HOME ? - Verá que esta combinação não cumpre com o propósito. Por isso o uso do comando `ls $HOME |`, esta implementado.

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma alternativa, que havia concluído antes da resposta do colega [cemdorst](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212262/41467). Coloco aqui apenas para que sirva de estudo podendo ser adptado para diversos fins:

```
 ls $HOME | while read LINE; do find /* -name "$LINE"; done | while read N; do tar -zcf ${N##*/}.tgz "$N" &>/dev/null; done
```

**Explicação**

`"$LINE"` - Note as aspas duplas que envolve a variável `LINE`, e esta por sua vez esta recebendo o fluxo de saída do comando `ls` onde estou apontando para o arquivo(s) e/ou diretório(s). Se nesse(s) arquivo(s) e diretório(s) possuíssem caracteres em branco(espaço em branco), então as aspas duplas `""` irá tratar para que o shell não interprete mal o que queremos.

Exemplo:

- /home/user/Downloads/Music/Mais_que_palavras_-_More_than_Words_(Versão Brasileira).ogg

então ficaria o nome do pacote assim ...

- Mais_que_palavras_-_More_than_Words_(Versão

Porque isto, ocorreu???

Porque houve um espaço em branco, neste ponto -> *(Versão Brasileira)*

Ou seja, o espaço em branco acabou com nossa alegria (menos o emprego)! O pacote ainda fora criado com sucesso, para corrigir isto seria necessário o `-print0` como fez o nosso caro colega [cemdorst](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212262/41467), em sua resposta.

`${N##*/}` - Ja neste outro ponto, estou apenas fazendo uma pequena [Expansão do Parâmetro do Shell](https://translate.google.com.br/translate?sl=en&tl=pt&js=y&prev=_t&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fsoftware%2Fbash%2Fmanual%2Fhtml_node%2FShell-Parameter-Expansion.html&edit-text=&act=url) para que atribua-se o nome do pacote sendo o mesmo do arquivo em questão, ou seja, o nome do arquivo que vier depois da última barra *slash* `/`.

**Exemplo:**

- /home/user/Downloads/Music/Mais_que_palavras_-_More_than_Words_(Versão_Brasileira).ogg

então ficaria o nome do pacote assim ...

- Mais_que_palavras_-_More_than_Words_(Versão_Brasileira).tgz

Observe que o uso desta expressão serve para isso, capturar o nome do arquivo depois da última barra invertida.

Comment: shell script: não importa quanto tempo você o conhece, não importa quantos cursos você já assistiu ou ministrou: sempre terá um detalhe a mais que lhe é novo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Então, a existência de diversas linguagens como *Perl,Tcl* dentre outras que se faz uso da **shell** juntamente com uso extensivos de comando fica inviável guardar tudo na nossa memória falha. E por outro lado conhecê-los completamente. Ja cheguei a fazer confusão com as função do *Bash* com a do *Javascript* por ser um pouco idêntica. Estava desenvolvendo uma página web, implementado uma função em *Javascript* com recursos do *Bash*. kkkkkkk

Answer (score 1):

## Vamos falar de Unix

O diretório corrente também é conhecido como *working directory*.

No mundo Unix, há o comando `pwd` que significa *print working directory*. Basicamente é um *built-in* disponível em quase todas as shells disponíveis. Também temos a variável `$PWD` que é basicamente uma variável com esse valor. [Esta resposta do unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175000) trata sobre mais nuanças.

Além disso, também tem um identificador relativo do diretório atual: `./`. Todas as paths que começam com `./` são relativas ao diretório atual; por exemplo, `./a.out` é o arquivo `a.out` localizado no diretório atual, enquanto que `./foo/bar` é o arquivo `bar` dentro da pasta `foo` que está no diretório atual. Também é possível deixar o entendimento implícito do path de um arquivo ao se retirar `./`: `a.out` e `foo/bar` dos exemplos anteriores.

> Quando se compila um arquivo em C com o GCC, ele produz o arquivo `a.out`. Para executar esse arquivo, normalmente se fala para por `./a.out`, mas não falam o motivo. Por que não simplesmente por `a.out`?, já que está no diretório atual? Porque o primeiro comando na shell precisa ser:
>
> 1. Um *built-in*
> 2. Uma função
> 3. O path completo (seja relativo ou absoluto) de um executável
> 4. O nome de um executável que está no `$PATH`
>
> A variável `$PATH` é relativo a outras coisas, mas é possível colocar `.` nela.

## Expansão Shell

Uma expansão no contexto Shell Script é mudar um texto por outro. Por exemplo, `echo $PWD` não simplesmente fará uma impressão do caminho atual. Acontecerá aqui uma expansão de variável, onde o texto `$PWD` será substituído pelo conteúdo da variável `$PWD` (`/home/jeff` por exemplo) e passará esse resultado para o comando *built-in* `echo`, como se o usuário tivesse escrito `echo /home/jeff`.

Uma outra expansão muito utilizada é a expansão ***glob***. Você usa essa expansão quando usa `ls foo/*.tar.*` ou `rm *.log`. Essa expansão é muito útil para listar conjuntos de arquivos que sigam um padrão. Mas, falando em padrão, isso não é coisa de expressão regular?

Bem, sim. Expressões regulares reconhecem padrões de texto. Expressões *glob*, por sua vez, reconhecem padrões em caminhos de arquivos.

Uma lista rápida sobre o que vai ser reconhecido em expansões *glob*:

- `*` : qualquer coisa de qualquer tamanho; equivalente ao `.*` das expressões regulares; obs: ignora arquivos em outros diretórios, leva em consideração apenas o diretório de onde se encontra o `*` na caminho a ser reconhecido
- `?` : um único caracter qualquer, equivalente ao `.` das expressões regulares; obs: esse caracter qualquer não pode ser um delimitador se diretório
- `[abc]` : é idêntico à lista das expressões regulares; obs: como nos outros, não pode representar mudança de diretório

Por exemplo, se quisermos adicionar ao elenco do git os arquivos `pom.xml` que estejam dentro de diretórios quaisquer das pastas que começam com `java`:

```
git add java*/*/pom.xml
```

Imagine que seja essa a estrutura de pastas:

```
jeff/
javado/
  -> jsp/
    -> pom.xml
  -> escovado/
javali/
  -> namesa/
    -> pom.xml
  -> janta/
    -> pom.xml
  -> muito/
javax/
```

Explicando aos poucos:

- `git add` : comando para adicionar arquivos ao elenco do git
- `java*/` : todos os diretórios, a partir do diretório corrente, que comecem com `java`, como `javado`, `javali`, `javax`
- `java*/*/` : todos os subdiretórios que tem como diretório pai o diretório que funciona no *match* descrito acima; exemplo: `javado/jsp`, `javado/escovado`, `javali/namesa`, `javali/janta`, `javali/muito`; nesse exemplo, `javax/` não tem subdiretórios
- `java*/*/pom.xml` : os arquivos `pom.xml` que estão no diretório do *match* anterior; exemplo: `javado/jsp/pom.xml`, `javali/namesa/pom.xml` e `javali/janta/pom.xml`

Dito isso acima, o shell interpretará a linha de comando como

```
git add javado/jsp/pom.xml javali/namesa/pom.xml javali/janta/pom.xml
```

e esse será o comando executado.

Outra expansão muito comum no shell é a expansão de comando. Resumindo, a expansão executará um comando interno e pegará a saída desse programa e o substituirá na linha de processamento. Essa expansão é indicada pela presença de `tick oi de`$(`dólar parêntese; nesse último caso, é necessário ter também um`)`

Voltemos ao exemplo acima. Vamos supor que os `pom.xml` sejam os únicos arquivos `.xml` de todo o projeto.

Para buscar todos os arquivos que terminam em `.xml`, posso usar o comando `find` desse jeito:

```
find ./ -name '*.xml'
```

Aos poucos:

- `find` : nome do programa
- `./` : o diretório de busca do `find` será o diretório corrente
- `-name` : um argumento do comando `find`, indica que o próximo argumento será o nome *glob-like* do arquivo desejado
- `'*.xml'` : em primeiro lugar, esse é o argumento do argumento `-name`; em segundo lugar, ao usar aspas simples, evitei toda e qualquer expansão; terceiro, como o `find` é recursivo, `*.xml` vai marcar positivo qualquer arquivo `.xml` independente de quão profundo estiver esse arquivo

A saída desse comando seria:

```
javado/jsp/pom.xml javali/janta/pom.xml javali/namesa/pom.xml
```

Daí, podemos usar a expansão de comando para o git.

```
git add `find ./ -name '*.xml'`
```

Depois da expansão, o comando fica:

```
git add javado/jsp/pom.xml javali/janta/pom.xml javali/namesa/pom.xml
```

> O comando `find` permite muito mais ações do que apenas imprimir arquivos que se encaixam em dadas expressões; vide a [*man page* do comando no Linux Die](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), estou apenas aproveitando o padrão dele que imprime os arquivos encontrados neste caso

## Compactação / Agregação de arquivos

Existem duas tarefas comum com gerenciamento de arquivos: compactação e agregação. Mas o que é cada um deles?

- agregação: a agregação de arquivos coloca vários arquivos em um único canto, de modo que você não precise enviar cada arquivo individualmente; o formato `tar` agrega arquivos de maneira não compactada, já o formato `zip` agrega arquivos compactados (cada arquivo inclusive pode ter uma compactação própria)
- compactação: a compactação tem como preocupação diminuir a quantidade de bytes de um arquivo; o formato `gz` é uma compactação bem padrão no mundo unix, `bz2` também é um formato popular de compactação; as entradas de um `zip` já estão compactadas, por isso é difícil conseguir compactar o arquivo `zip` ainda mais

Vale notar que `tar.gz` é a compactação `gzip` aplicada sobre um arquivo agregador `tar`; a extensão `tgz` é um jeito reduzido de se escrever `tar.gz`. A extensão `tar.bz2` é análogo ao `tar.gz` para a compactação `bz2`.

O comando `tar` serve para criar arquivos agregados `tar`, assim como manipulá-los também. Para criar um arquivo `tar`, podemos usar o seguinte comando:

```
tar -cf agregado.tar arquivoA arquivoB
```

Aos poucos:

- `tar` : comando para criar/manipular arquivos agregados
- `-cf` : equivalente a `-c -f`, nessa ordem; é muito comum opções de linha de comando curtas serem agregadas precedidas por um único traço `-`
- `-c` : flag para indicar que será criado um novo arquivo
- `-f` : flag que necessita de argumento, indica qual será o arquivo a ser manipulado (neste exemplo, o arquivo será criado)
- `agregado.tar` : o argumento da flag `-f`, é o nome do arquivo sendo manipulado
- `arquivoA arquivoB` : todos os outros argumentos que não sejam argumentos de flag são os caminhos dos arquivos/diretórios que serão agregados; neste caso apenas dois arquivos, `arquivoA` e `arquivoB`

Nos primórdios, o comando `tar` só servia para o fim de manipular arquivos `tar`, mas então devido à popularidade dos arquivos `tar` compactado, ele começou a ter opções de compactação também. O seguinte exemplo cria o `tar.gz` do exemplo anterior em um único comando:

```
tar -czf compact.tar.gz arquivoA arquivoB
```

De novidade aqui apenas a flag `-z`, que indica que se deve usar a compactação `gzip` sobre o `tar` gerado.

## Compactando todos os arquivos de um diretório individualmente

Como cada arquivo será compactado individualmente, não precisamos agregá-los. Então basta chamar o compactador, `gzip`. Sabendo qual o comando que será chamado, precisamos agora saber como iremos iterar sobremos arquivos.

Vou colocar o comando a ser executado em uma função, `compactfile`, assim outro comando de compactação pode ser usado.

### Criação de `compactfile`

A priori, precisamos apenas chamar o comando `gzip` com o arquivo desejado.

```
compactfile() {
    arquivo_original="$1"

    gzip "$arquivo_original"
}
```

E se eu quiser um *dry run*? Bem, poderíamos emular um *dry run* assim:

```
compactfile_dryrun() {
    arquivo_original="$1"

    echo gzip "$arquivo_original"
}
```

Bem, podemos tentar unificar esses dois comandos em um só... vamos delegar para o próximo momento o como é feita a detecção se é *dry run*, por hora vai ser hard coded se é ou não *dry run*:

```
compactfile() {
    dryrun=true # se não for dry run, só por false aqui
    base_cmd='gzip'

    arquivo_original="$1"

    cmd_args="$base_cmd \"$arquivo_original\""

    $dryrun && cmd_final="echo $cmd_args" || cmd_final="$cmd_args"

    $cmd_final
}
```

Bem, agora sobre a detecção do *dry run*... eu vejo normalmente usarem duas alternativas para isso: `-n` e `--dry-run`. Vamos por essa detecção com um `case`?

```
compactfile() {
    dryrun=false

    case "$1" in
         -n|--dry-run)
             dryrun=true # detectei que quero fazer uma dry run
             shift # remove o primeiro argumento e puxa os seguintes em uma posição
             ;;
    esac

    base_cmd='gzip'

    arquivo_original="$1"

    cmd_args="$base_cmd \"$arquivo_original\""

    $dryrun && cmd_final="echo $cmd_args" || cmd_final="$cmd_args"

    $cmd_final
}
```

### Iteração `for`, lista com glob

Iterar sobre um glob puro tem a desvantagem de não acessar recursivamente os arquivos.
Só conseguimos pegar aqueles que estão no nível do diretório corrente (vou fazer *dry run* só para mostrar qual será o efeitos cada ponto):

```
compactdir=.
for arq in $compactdir/*; do
    if [ -f "$arq" ]; then
        compactfile -n "$arq"
    fi
done
```

Bem, agora eu mostrei duas novas estruturas do shell:

- `if` : estrutura sintática da forma `if CMD; then CMD_IF; else CMD_ELSE; fi`; a parte do `else` é opcional; se `CMD` retornar verdadeiro (retorno 0), executa o bloco de comandos `CMD_IF`; caso seja falso (retorno diferente de 0) e exista `else`, executa o bloco de comandos `CMD_ELSE`;
- comando `test conditions`, ou sintaxe `[ conditions ]` : a estrutura sintática que começa com `[` tem o mesmo efeito que o comando `test`, apenas exige que seja fechado com um `]`; no caso, `-f` é um operador unário que verifica a existência de um arquivo comum (diretórios não servem), retornado verdadeiro caso ele exista e falso caso contrário; você pode ler mais sobre o comando `test` [na documentação](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test)

> Nota sobre a sintaxe `[ conditions ]`:
>   Os espaços são **OBRIGATÓRIOS**, senão o shell vai entender outra coisa

### Iteração `for`, usando expansão do comando `find`

```
compactdir=.
for arq in `find $compactdir/`; do
    if [ -f "$arq" ]; then
        compactfile -n "$arq"
    fi
done
```

### Iterando no próprio `find`

O [@cemdorst](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15263/cemdorst) colocou isso [na resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212262/64969). Devo admitir que não sabia disso até então. Adaptando o que ele usou com a função de compactação personalizado `compactfile`, temos o código a seguir.

> Também devo admitir que demorei muito para responder

```
compactdir=.
find $compactdir -print0 -exec compactfile -n '{}' \;
```