# Como alterar as coordenadas cartesianas de arquivos, de forma automatizada

Tags: linux, script, bash, while, sed

Eu tenho uma determinada pasta com diversos arquivos, e estes por sua vez, contém em seu interior descrição de pontos de coordenadas *cartesianas* X e Y.

No entanto, quero fazer a substituição desses pontos de modo automático e dinânmico, ou seja, usar `while` para correr todos esses arquivos rodando o `sed` para alterar os valores do eixo X e Y dos arquivos.

Bom, o que se torna o ponto crucial aqui, é fazer a inserção vinda de um somador/contador até findar todos os arquivos contido na pasta.

O detalhe fica por conta de que, para cada 5(cinco) arquivos o Y deve receber valores idênticos, e os próximos 5 arquivos, é posto um novo número dando um salto de 0 - 5. Veja o exemplo:

lista dos primeiros 5 arquivos:

X: 100
  Y: 0

X: 200
  Y: 0

X: 300
  Y: 0

X: 400
  Y: 0

X: 500
  Y: 0

lista dos próximos 5 arquivos:

X: 600
  Y: 5

X: 700
  Y: 5

X: 800
  Y: 5

X: 900
  Y: 5

X: 1000
  Y: 5

lista dos 5 arquivos seguintes:

X: 1100
  Y: 10

X: 1200
  Y: 10

X: 1300
  Y: 10

X: 1400
  Y: 10

X: 1500
  Y: 10

Acho que ja deu pra compreender a lógica toda né! Os pontos vão sendo somado por números inteiros a um contador, que os coloca na medida de uma entrada de 5 arquivos por vez, começando pelo número 100 para o eixo X, e logo após o segundo X do segundo arquivo para 200, e para o terceiro arquivo 300, no quarto arquivo X 400 e no quinto arquivo com eixo X 500.

Continua calculando/somando de 100 em 100 e adicionando nos próxmimos 5 arquivos, e assim se faz por cada 5 ciclos de arquivos. Isto é para o eixo X, ja para o Y, seria quase a mesma coisa, no entanto temos de levar em conta o valor é menor, sendo de 5 em 5 considerando que deve setar o mesmo valor para os 5 primeiros arquivos e fazer novamente a soma para os próximos 5 arquivos e etc...

## Exemplo

```
#!/bin/sh
X=100;
Y=0;
while [ $Y -lt 5 ]; do
   echo -e "X: $X\r";
   echo -e "Y: $Y\n";
   let X=$X+1;
   let Y=$Y+1;
done
```

Segue o resultado após executar o script

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A matemática é fácil de se fazer com shell, mas devo admitir que fiquei um tanto perdido com a estruturação e distribuição dos arquivos. Pode mostrar um exemplo do antes e depois? Com os nomes dos arquivos desejados e tal?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Você pode querer montar essa estruturação para ter uma idéia no seu próprio sistema operacinal que esteja usando seja MAC ou LINUX. Faça `$ mkdir teste`, e depois crie alguns arquivos em branco com o seguinte comando: `$ for ARQ in {0..15}; do touch teste/$ARQ; done`, dai você terá apenas o trabalho de abri-los e acrescentar as coordenadas **X 0** e **Y 0** para todos demais, será igual. Agora que preciso é elaboração do script onde deverá ir somando e incrementando e substituindo esses zero(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos iterar sobre uma quantidade de coordenadas desejadas. Para isso, vou precisar um pouco de aritmética inteira na *bash* e, na iteração, vamos usar uma expansão de comando (eu falo mais sobre expansões de comando [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212632/64969)).

## Aritmética inteira

Um básico de aritmética sobre números inteiros. Isso é algo built-in no *bash*, então vou me apropriar dessa matemática na resposta.

Responda rápido, quanto é `(x/5) * 5`? Se você pensou que é `x`, você ainda está nos números reais, e estaria certo se a pergunta fosse sobre a operação divisão sobre os números reais. No caso de divisão inteira, ela é um operador binário sobre dois inteiros resultando em um outro inteiro:

[image: Divisão: operação binária sobre inteiros resultando em inteiros]

Então, considerando a pergunta agora sobre aritmética inteira, qual o resultado de `(x/5) * 5`?

Pondo em palavras, a resposta é:

> O maior múltiplo de 5 menor do que ou igual a `x`

Também é possível escrever de outra forma isso, de maneira mais algébrica:

> `x - (x % 5)`

Ok, interessante, mas por que isso é importante?

Para fazer os cálculos. Eu incremento o valor de `Y` a cada 5 iterações, na razão de 5 unidades. Olhe o pseudo-código a seguir:

```
x0 é fornecido como 100
y0 é fornecido como 0

x_inc é fornecido como 100
y_inc é fornecido como 5

y_step é fornecido como 5

para i no intervalo [0, 49]:
    x = x0 + i * x_inc
    y = y0 + (i/y_step) * y_inc

    operação com x e y
```

Onde:

> `x0` é o valor inicial de `x`
>   `y0` é o valor inicial de `y`
>   `x_inc` é o quanto `x` tem o valor incrementado a cada salto
>   `y_inc` é o quanto `y` tem o valor incrementado a cada salto
>   `y_step` é o número de iterações antes de haver um incremento de `y`

## Expansão aritmética inteira

Em *bash*, para fazer a expansão aritmética, você precisa estar no ambiente aritmético. Ele começa com `$((` e termina com `))` (os espaços nos meus testes não se mostraram necessários, mas [*bash* é uma linguagem sagrada ;-)](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Bash) que precisa respeitar os espaços).

Rode isso como exemplo:

```
echo $(( 13/5 ))
x=49
echo $(( (x/5) * 5 ))
echo $(( x - (x%5) ))
```

No ambiente aritmético as variáveis são interpretadas, não precisando portanto por o `$` para forças sua expansão.

## Solução

Vou usar o pseudo-código acima como base para criar o script em *bash*. Note que a *shebang* do *bash* é `#!/bin/bash`, não `#!/bin/sh`. `#!/bin/sh` aponta para a shell padrão do sistema, que as vezes pode ser a própria **Bourne Shell**; *bash* é uma evolução dessa shell, a **Bourne-Again Shell**. Eu não gosto de usar `#!/bin/sh`, em diversos computadores que eu peguei no começo da década de 2010 ainda usava a *Bourne Shell* e não tinha a sintaxe que eu gostaria de usar da *bash*.

```
#!/bin/bash

x0=100
y0=0

# incrementos
x_inc=100
y_inc=5

y_step=5

# quantidade de coordenadas desejadas
n_coords=50

for i in `seq 0 $(( n_coords - 1 ))`; do
    x=$(( x0 + i*x_inc ))
    y=$(( y0 + (i/y_step)*y_inc ))

    echo "X:$x Y:$y" > teste/$i
done
```

Comment: @DiegoHenrique, note que é mais fácil criar o arquivo do que editar seu conteúdo (se o conteúdo do arquivo é somente a coordenada). Mesmo assim, dá para fazer a subtituição caso seja necessário usando o `sed`, mas recomendo apenas em casos onde há mais informações nesses arquivos

Comment: @DiegoHenrique, acabei de atualizar redirecionando a saída para ser de acordo com [o seu c omentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213589/como-alterar-as-coordenadas-cartesianas-de-arquivos-de-forma-automatizada/213733#comment436737_213589)

Comment: O arquivo original tem sim mais linhas em seu conteúdo. Mas para fins didáticos coloquei na pergunta e no comentário arquivos fictícios para se ter uma noção de maneira isolada do propósito principal.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique vou atualizar para usar `sed` como deveria ser, mas não posso agora ;-)